# Keycloak 19.0.2 ECP Profile tab

Tags: java, keycloak, keycloak-rest-api, keycloak-connect

In keycloak 19.0.2 how can we enable ECP flow?

There is no option provided on UI part.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.